# TypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) within GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

Within the GAE I'm getting an error telling me:

**TypeError: get_default_tile() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)**

As you can see the code from my main py file **get_default_tile()** is being passed only one argument which is *name*:

```
 default_tile = self.get_default_tile(name)
```

The full code follows:

```
import jinja2   # html template libary
import os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

import urllib   
import urllib2 
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch


class Default_tiles(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  image = db.BlobProperty(default=None)


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    # this just prints out the url which the user enters into input
    image_name = self.request.get('image_name') 

    template_values = {
        'image_name': image_name,
    }

    template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))



class Upload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):

    # get information from form post upload
    image_url = self.request.get('image_url') 
    image_name = self.request.get('image_name')

    # create database entry for uploaded image 
    default_tile = Default_tiles()
    default_tile.name = image_name
    default_tile.image = db.Blob(urlfetch.Fetch(image_url).content)
    default_tile.put()

    self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode({'image_name': image_name}))


class Get_default_tile(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    name = self.request.get('image_name')
    default_tile = self.get_default_tile(name)

    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
    self.response.out.write(default_tile.image)

  def get_default_tile(name):
    result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Default_tiles WHERE name = :1 LIMIT 1", name).fetch(1)
    if (len(result) > 0):
      return result[0]
    else:
      return None


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/upload', Upload),
                               ('/default_tile_img', Get_default_tile)],
                              debug=True)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_default_tile():` is a member method of class `Get_default_tile` so you need to define it like this:

`def get_default_tile(self, name):`

Or if you want it to be a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def get_default_tile(name):
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i getting too that erro but the code following:

> class myclassname( webapp2.RequestHandler ):
>
> ```
>  def get(self):
>
>      self.response.write('hola')
> ```

i solved with =

> class myclassname( webapp2.RequestHandler ):
>
> ```
>  def get(self, **name**):
>
>      self.response.write('hola')
> ```